Set focus and make the first child tab active upon clicking the parent tab
Here, I'm populating nested tabs based on the settings of linked custom objects. Based on the child tab selected, I dynamically instantiate various child lwc components. When I reselect a previously active parent tab, the lwc tabset defaults to focusing on the last active child tab of that particular parent. I want to achieve whenever I click on any parent tab, it will automatically focus on the first child tab. Any help is greatly appreciated.
<template>
 <div  class="slds-box slds-theme_default" >
 <lightning-tabset active-tab-value="">
    <template for:each={tabList} for:item="tab"  >

        <lightning-tab value={tab.parentTab} label={tab.parentTab} key={tab.parentTab}
         onactive={handleParentTabClick}>    

            <lightning-tabset variant="scoped" active-tab-value=""  >
                <template for:each={tab.subTabs} for:item="subTab" >
                <lightning-tab label={subTab} key={subTab} name={subTab} onactive={handleSubTabClick} 
                     class="hide-border">
                    <!-- {subTab} -->
                    
                </lightning-tab>
                </template>
            </lightning-tabset>
         </lightning-tab>
    </template>
</lightning-tabset>
<!-- <c-parent-place-holder></c-parent-place-holder> -->
<div  class="slds-box">
    <lwc:component lwc:is={componentConstructor} lwc:ref="myCmp"></lwc:component>

</div>
</div>

 </template>

Js code
import tabConfiguration from "@salesforce/apex/TabConfigurationEngine.getTabDeatails";
import {IsConsoleNavigation,getFocusedTabInfo,setTabLabel} from 'lightning/platformWorkspaceApi';


const TAB_LABEL = 'Dynamic Tabs';

export default class DynamicTab extends LightningElement {
static delegatesFocus = true;
hasRendered;


tabList;
hasError=false;
activeParenttab;
componentConstructor;

 @wire(IsConsoleNavigation) isConsoleNavigation;

// Set tab label
 async setTabLabel() {
        if (!this.isConsoleNavigation) {
            return;
        }
        const { tabId } = await getFocusedTabInfo();
        setTabLabel(tabId, TAB_LABEL);
    }

     connectedCallback() {
         this.setTabLabel();
    }

//  Load Tab and Sub-tabs from custom objects
@wire(tabConfiguration)
    tabView(response) {        
            if(response.data){
                try{

                this.tabList =response.data.parentTabList;
                this.activeParenttab=response.data.activeParentTabName
                console.log('Name :',this.activeParenttab)
                console.log('tabList :',JSON.stringify(this.tabList));
               
                }
               catch( error){
                    console.log('Error ',error);
               }
                
            }
            if(response.error){
                this.hasError=true;
            }
        }

       renderedCallback(){
         console.log('rendered callback called');
         if(!this.hasRendered){
            this.hasRendered=true;
            this.template.querySelector('lightning-tabset').activeTabValue = this.activeParenttab;
            this.hasRendered=true;
         }
         
       }

       handleSubTabClick(event){
        console.log('sub tab clicked '+event.target.name);
        let clickedtab=event.target.name
        
        //this.template.querySelector('lightning-tabset').activeTabValue = event.target.value;
         //event.currentTarget.classList.add('slds-theme_shade')
         if(clickedtab==="Today's Order"){
           // event.target.classList.add('slds-theme_shade')
             console.log('loadComponent called')
           this.loadComponent('parentPlaceHolder');
         }
         else{
            this.componentConstructor=null;
         }
         
       }

       handleParentTabClick(e){
           this.componentConstructor=null;
           console.log('Parent tab clicked');          
        //    const name=this.template.querySelector('lightning-tabset')
        //    console.log('name ',name)
        //    const allTabs = document.querySelectorAll('ul>li');
        //    allTabs.forEach( (elm, idx) =>{
        //     console.log(elm);
        //      elm.classList.remove("slds-is-active")
        //  })
        // e.currentTarget.classList.add('slds-is-active')
       }

        async loadComponent(lwcCmp) {
            console.log('Async loading..')
            const lwcComp=`c/${lwcCmp}`
            const ctor = await import(lwcComp);
            this.componentConstructor = ctor.default;
            console.log('Async loading complete..')
    }

    
       
}

JSON data that I am retrieving from apex classes.
tabList : [{"parentTab":"Customer","subTabs":["Search Customer","Deactiave Customer","Re-Activate Customer"]},{"parentTab":"Order","subTabs":["Today's Order","Order History","Order Details"]},{"parentTab":"Promotion / Voucher / Discount","subTabs":["View Applied Promotion","View Order Item Promotions","View Customer Promotions"]},{"parentTab":"Payments","subTabs":["View Payment Details","Order"]}]


Do you have checked this? - Apply Focus on Child Component

Tried this also, but it is not working out.
